# phpmyadmin copy text from one field to another

Tags: phpmyadmin, copy, field

In phpmyadmin table products_description I want to copy all the text from the field "products_name" to the field "products_head_title_tag" but if the field "products_head_title_tag" already has some text then I dont want it to copy it. How can this be done?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your data before trying this:

```
update products_description set products_head_title_tag = products_name WHERE products_head_title_tag IS NULL;
```